# I can't install eventmachine gem on mac m1

Tags: ruby, rubygems, apple-m1, eventmachine

I got a new m1 mac and I can't install `eventmachine` gem, full log below.

I tried these solutions:

- [Install gem eventmachine 1.2.7 with ssl on m1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68730953/install-gem-eventmachine-1-2-7-with-ssl-on-m1)
- eventmachine does not compile with ruby 3.0.0preview1 on macOS · Issue #932 · eventmachine/eventmachine

same error.

some info:

```
   $ sw_vers
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 12.2
BuildVersion:   21D49

   $ bundle --version
Bundler version 2.1.4
```

and the error:

```
   $ gem install eventmachine -v '1.2.7'
```

```
em.cpp:706:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_thread_select'; did you mean 'rb_thread_fd_select'?
        if ((ret = rb_thread_select(kqfd + 1, &fdreads, NULL, NULL, &tv)) < 1) {
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                   rb_thread_fd_select
```

Full output: https://gist.github.com/goldylucks/8369ea09af4f3f70d707809f4bb700df

any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: FWIW, I was just able to install it just fine on my M1. Have you tried running the same command on a different version of Ruby? 2.5 should be supported, but I wonder if there is some other conflict such as your OpenSSL version (see: https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/951)

Comment: See https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/588, which relates to the  `rb_thread_select` error.

Answer (score 35):

I solved this (thanks to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/riffraff/status/1573204825260580864)) with the following:

```
gem install eventmachine -v '1.2.7' -- --with-ldflags="-Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup"
```

Comment: This appeared to fix my install (finally) but running a `bundle exec middleman build` caused `Unable to load the EventMachine C extension; To use the pure-ruby reactor, require 'em/pure_ruby'
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/3.1.0/prettyprint.rb:182:in 'text': can't convert Middleman::CoreExtensions::Collections::LazyCollectorStep to String (Middleman::CoreExtensions::Collections::LazyCollectorStep#to_str gives Middleman::CoreExtensions::Collections::LazyCollectorStep) (TypeError)
`

Comment: This worked for me on Monterey (12.4) trying to install under Ruby 2.7.1. I mostly run a local jekyll installation, so I haven't really tested in beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

what solved it for me was installing ruby like this:

```
$ arch -x86_64 rbenv install 2.5.5 # or using rvm
```